# Find location of unknown point with geosphere distances to two known points

Tags: r

Using code I generated from the accepted answer to a previous question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112905/map-location-of-unknown-point-with-distances-to-two-known-points, I am unclear in what units the results are produced? They do not appear to be in Long/Lat decimal values, as my inputs are.

Create a small, sample dataframe:

```
group    <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
distance <- c(709, 2283, 5515, 3035, 4471) ##in km
long     <- c(20.5, 29.4, -14.3, 9.85, -5.5)
lat      <- c(-19.6, 1.6, 10.9, 2.3, 7.5)
df       <- data.frame(group, distance, long, lat)
> df
  group distance  long   lat
1     A      709  20.5 -19.6
2     B     2283  29.4   1.6
3     C     5515 -14.3  10.9
4     D     3035  9.85   2.3
5     E     4471  -5.5   7.5
```

The function `combn` creates a matrix of indices of all pairwise row comparisons, and with the `FUN` argument I find the location of an unknown point using two known points and two known distances at a time:

```
library(geosphere) ##load package for distVincentyEllipsoid function

locations <-  combn(nrow(df), 2, FUN=\(x) {i <- x[1]; j <- x[2];   
  P0 <- df[i, c("long", "lat")]
  x0 <- df[i, "long"]
  y0 <- df[i, "lat"]
  r0 <- df[i, "distance"]
  P1 <- df[j, c("long", "lat")]
  x1 <- df[j, "long"]
  y1 <- df[j, "lat"]
  r1 <- df[j, "distance"]
  d  <- abs(distVincentyEllipsoid(
      P1,
      P0,
      a = 6378137,
      b = 6356752.3142,
      f = 1 / 298.257223563
    ) / 1000)                  ##d in km
  a  <- (r0 ^ 2 - r1 ^ 2 + d ^ 2) / (2 * d)
  h  <- (r0 ^ 2 - a ^ 2) ^ 2
  x2 <- x0 + a * (x1 - x0) / d
  y2 <- y0 + a * (y1 - y0) / d
  x3.1 <- x2 + h * (y1 - y0) / d
  y3.1 <- y2 + h * (x1 - x0) / d
  x3.2 <- x2 - h * (y1 - y0) / d
  y3.2 <- y2 - h * (x1 - x0) / d
  locations <- cbind(x3.1, y3.1, x3.2, y3.2)}  ) ##this creates an array

locations <- matrix(locations, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE) ##change the array into a matrix
```

Here's how I want the output to look for one row pair, in the form of matrix `locations`:

```
P0 <- df[df$group == "A", c("long", "lat")] 
x0 <- df[df$group == "A", "long"]
y0 <- df[df$group == "A", "lat"]
r0 <- df[df$group == "A", "distance"] 

P1 <- df[df$group == "B", c("long", "lat")] 
x1 <- df[df$group == "B", "long"]
y1 <- df[df$group == "B", "lat"]
r1 <- df[df$group == "B", "distance"] 

d  <- abs(distVincentyEllipsoid(P1, P0, a = 6378137, b = 6356752.3142, f = 1 / 298.257223563) / 1000)
a  <- (r0 ^ 2 - r1 ^ 2 + d ^ 2) / (2 * d)
h  <- (r0 ^ 2 - a ^ 2) ^ 2
x2 <- x0 + a * (x1 - x0) / d
y2 <- y0 + a * (y1 - y0) / d
x3.1 <- x2 + h * (y1 - y0) / d
y3.1 <- y2 + h * (x1 - x0) / d
x3.2 <- x2 - h * (y1 - y0) / d
y3.2 <- y2 - h * (x1 - x0) / d
locations <- cbind(x3.1, y3.1, x3.2, y3.2)

> locations
           x3.1      y3.1        x3.2       y3.2
[1,] 1243177033 521899766 -1243176990 -521899800
```

The output is consistent each time, but I don't know what to do with it. I was expecting Long/Lat in decimal form.

Comment: From docs (`distVincentyEllipsoid {geosphere}`): "Distance value in the same units as the ellipsoid (default is meters)". So everything that is assigned to `d` is in meters

Comment: Aside: since the longitudinal distance varies with latitude *when expressed in degrees*, values expressed in length units (see @asd-tm 's comment) are easier comparable.

Comment: You may also find useful: `maptools::gcDestination()`

Comment: @asd-tm: Everything after ```d``` mixes the distance with the long/lat in decimal, so ```x3.1, y3.1, x3.2, and y3.2``` are some ambiguous mixture I cannot figure out. The issue with ```maptools::gcDestination()``` and similar ```geosphere::destPoint()``` is the requirement of a bearing, which I do not have and would have to make up to make the function work.

Comment: @I_O: Are you suggesting I convert the coordinate system from Long/Lat decimal geodetic to something else? I tried converting them to radian and then to Cartesian Earth-centered, Earth Fixed (ECEF), but once I went Cartesian I had trouble getting back to Long/Lat decimal again. I tried converting Cartesian even with a WGS84 crs to radian, and then radian to decimal. However, I failed when converting Cartesian to radian, I seemed to only be able to convert to polar coordinates and then lost all reference to the Earth.

Comment: If bearing is the issue you may use `maptools::gzAzimuth()`

Comment: @asd-tm I guess I'm seeing a chicken-egg situation, where I don't know what ```maptools``` calls the "destination". So, to calculate the bearings I need to know the unknown point, and to identify the unknown point I need the bearings. If I create bearings, I would be guessing at the location of the "destination", so when I use those bearing to find ```gcDestination``` it would be biased toward my guess. If I'm interpreting these functions correctly..

Comment: For a quick solution, I'd find an *equidistant* projection for your area of interest (https://projectionwizard.org/), convert your lon/lat to planar coordinates, buffer the two known points with their respective distance from the unknown point and intersect the resulting two circles (note there'll be two solutions for each pair). Package {sf} supplies the functions `st_points`, `st_transform`, `st_buffer` and `st_intersection` for this. An alternative though less straightforward approach would be to stick with {geosphere} and `optim`ise (minimise) the distance between estimates.

Comment: @I_O Using projectionwizard.org, the Distortion Property "Equidistant", I zoom in on my area of interest, and I use those WestLongitude, SouthLatitude, EastLongitude, NorthLatitude as my  ```sf``` ```st_transform``` ```aoi```. Then, at the bottom of the webpage I see a "center latitude" and a "center longitude", above which says this: "Azimuthal equidistant PROJ WKT". What is my projection?

Comment: You're right: the projection wizard doesn't offer a projection for that area. You can google some other tool, or roll your own projection like explained here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364268/choosing-appropriate-projected-coordinate-system-for-africa

Comment: @I_O For two sites in df: ```points <-  st_sfc(st_point(c(20.5, -19.6), st_point(c(29.4, 1.6)), crs = 4326)``` ```planar <- st_transform(x = points, crs = st_crs(points), aoi = c(-18.281389, -40.98, 56.25, 38.8225), dst = "+proj=chamb +lat_1=22 +lon_1=0 +lat_2=22 +lon_2=45 +lat_3=-22 +lon_3=22.5 +datum=WGS84 +type=crs")``` ```dist <- c(709.7, 2283)*1000 #in m``` ```buffer<- st_buffer(x = planar, dist = dist)``` and ```intersect.location <- st_intersection(x = buffer[[1]], y = buffer[[2]])``` gives me many points of intersection even though ```plot(buffer)``` clearly shows only 2 points?

Comment: Also, converting decimal long/lat to planar did not change the values, did I do something wrong?

Comment: If you `st_cast` buffer[[1]] to LINESTRING, and also for buffer[[2]] (using your comment just above), i.e.  `buf1_ls <- st_cast(buffer[[1]], 'LINESTRING')`, same for `buf2_ls`, and intersect those, you'll get a geometry collection back of a 'LINESTRING' and a 'POINT'. Further `st_cast`ing  the returned line string to POINT will return the first point in the line string, and hence the two points of intersection you'd expect.  This just from the above comment data. Some results may be two points. Some may be POINT, LINESTRING. More data would tell, but it drives it down to to possible locations.

Comment: @Chris Using the sample dataframe in the question and the commented code to get the buffers, add this code for each pair of locations ```coordsB <- st_cast(buffer[[1]], 'LINESTRING')
  coordsC <- st_cast(buffer[[2]], 'LINESTRING')
  # find intersections
  coords <- st_intersection(x = coordsB, y = coordsC)
  nums   <- list(coords)```. Some intersections (i.e. group A to group D) have more than two points? And if converting decimal long/lat to planar did not change the values, did I do something wrong? Do I need to back translate from planar into long/lat decimal?

Comment: The projected planar give more reliable distance measures than long/lat. The linestring from the intersection is a result of floating point instability, buf1_2_intersect = st_intersection(x = buf1_linestring, y = buf2_linestring), `st_length(buf1_2_intersect[[1]])
[1] 0.08455787`, the error of where the point could be, `lengths(buf1_2_intersect) [1] 4 2` tests for which is linestring [4], or point [2], and apologize, was treating this as `sf` features, hadn't gotten to the sample df (geosphere above) yet. But the A D intersect not returning 4 values says linestrings not points so same prob.

Comment: @Chris Okay, so I keep the transformation into planar at the beginning and then back-transform from planar to Long/Lat decimals at the end. Even though they do not appear to be different values in planar vs Long/Lat decimal. 

You are saying I cannot use the Linestring coordinates as possible candidates, because those actually represent points along the great circles and not the actual intersection points?

Comment: You can absolutely use either linestring coord as intersection point (with error term if relevant), Returned points resolved mathematically, unambiguously, while line says it could be the point at either end (or anywhere in between). Is it i big error, 8.455% of a meter, or is it small when distributed across the great circle distance in meters, if an argument can be made. If you edit your ? title to R geosphere find location...package author Robert Hijmans will likely arrive to answer. In my `sf` approach was just lucky returns geometrycollection, rather than error whereas array likely errors

Comment: @Chris I changed the title. Here's hoping he sees it and comes to save the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treasure maps are meant to obscure, but, with a 'set' of details the relationship between set members may be such as to reveal that part that was meant to be harder to find (perhaps colleagues steal one's research ideas...). So, assuming the details of the set are meaningful, perhaps `geosphere::greatCircles` will help here:

```
library(geodata)
library(geosphere)
# using `df` as above
# have a subdirectory in working directory called 'maps`
countries <- world(resolution = 5, path = "maps")
A_mtx = matrix(unlist(df[1, 3:4]), nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
B_mtx = matrix(unlist(df[2, 3:4]), nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
C_mtx = matrix(unlist(df[3, 3:4]), nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
D_mtx = matrix(unlist(df[4, 3:4]), nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
E_mtx = matrix(unlist(df[5, 3:4]), nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
c_codes = country_codes()
# `merge` c_codes with countries
countries = merge(countries, c_codes, by.x = 'GID_0', by.y='ISO3', all.x = TRUE)
png(file = 'greatCircles_to_treasure.png')
plot(countries[which(countries$continent == 'Africa')])
lines(greatCircle(A_mtx, B_mtx, n = 360), col = 'red')
lines(greatCircle(A_mtx, C_mtx, n = 360), col = 'red')
lines(greatCircle(A_mtx, D_mtx, n = 360), col = 'red')
lines(greatCircle(A_mtx, E_mtx, n = 360), col = 'red')
dev.off()
```

This shows promise

[image]

but we'll likely want to do some more testing, and testing suggests coming back to `geosphere` functions after an excursion through `sf`.
Up in the comments, buffering points to distance is suggested, and that is the approach taken as it can (somewhat) answer when all cases == TRUE. We'll continue as well with `geodata` maps, trimmed down to a 'study_area'. What I'll suggest is that we are looking for consensus of 'about where' the unknown origin is located. The about where part is introduced by the ruler used and significant digits in `df$distance`.

```
library(sf)
# and library(geodata), and taking the above 'africa' map to study_area
study_area = africa[africa$NAME_0 == 'Angola' | africa$NAME_0 == 'Zambia' | africa$NAME_0 == 'Zimbabwe' | africa$NAME_0 == 'Namibia' | africa$NAME_0 == 'Botswana', ]

# our points
pts_sfc = st_sfc(st_point(A_mtx), st_point(B_mtx), st_point(C_mtx), st_point(D_mtx), st_point(E_mtx))

st_crs(pts_sfc) = 4326
# buffer
A_buffer = st_buffer(pts_sfc[1], dist = df$distance[1] *1000, nQuadSegs = 30)
B_buffer = st_buffer(pts_sfc[2], dist = df$distance[2] *1000, nQuadSegs = 60)
C_buffer = st_buffer(pts_sfc[3], dist = df$distance[3] *1000, nQuadSegs = 180)
D_buffer = st_buffer(pts_sfc[4], dist = df$distance[4] *1000, nQuadSegs = 120)
E_buffer = st_buffer(pts_sfc[5], dist = df$distance[5] *1000, nQuadSegs = 180)
# just pull the boundary using `st_boundry(`
# so, above could be A_boundary = st_boundary(st_buffer(pts_sfc[1]...
A_bound = st_boundary(A_buffer)
B_bound = st_boundary(B_buffer)
C_bound = st_boundary(C_buffer)
D_bound = st_boundary(D_buffer)
E_bound = st_boundary(E_buffer)

# st_intersection
AB_inter = st_intersection(A_bound, B_bound)
AC_inter = st_intersection(A_bound, C_bound)
AD_inter = st_intersection(A_bound, D_bound)
AE_inter = st_intersection(A_bound, E_bound)
```

examine intersection output

```
AB_inter
Geometry set for 2 features 
Geometry type: GEOMETRY
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 16.44059 ymin: -18.92567 xmax: 27.26761 ymax: -14.44397
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
POINT (27.26761 -18.92567)
LINESTRING (16.44059 -14.44397, 16.44059 -14.53...

# a Point and Linestring

AC_inter
Geometry set for 1 feature 
Geometry type: MULTIPOINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 20.33088 ymin: -26.06643 xmax: 27.17353 ymax: -18.24369
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
MULTIPOINT ((27.12648 -18.25086), (27.17353 -18...
# Dang, a Multipoint, how indecisive!
# st_cast this to points
AC_inter_pts = st_cast(st_sfc(AC_inter), 'POINT')
AC_inter_pts
Geometry set for 3 features 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 20.33088 ymin: -26.06643 xmax: 27.17353 ymax: -18.24369
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
POINT (27.12648 -18.25086)
POINT (27.17353 -18.24369)
POINT (20.33088 -26.06643)
AD_inter_pts
Geometry set for 2 features 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 15.876 ymin: -24.4339 xmax: 27.26761 ymax: -19.10002
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
POINT (27.26761 -19.10002)
POINT (15.876 -24.4339)
> AE_inter_pts
Geometry set for 2 features 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 18.80762 ymin: -25.82576 xmax: 26.89103 ymax: -17.59025
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
POINT (26.89103 -17.59025)
POINT (18.80762 -25.82576)
```

Suppose, in pursuing consensus, we develop a hunch that the origin must be constrained to a given area and we want to test our many intersections against that area, using our intersection output from above:

```
library(lwgeom)
# hunch is it is somewhere between AD_inter_pts[1] and AE_inter_pts[1]
# create a polygon to intersect
origin_hunch = st_minimum_bounding_circle(st_combine(c(AD_inter_pts[1], AE_inter_pts[1])))
# testing if line string in AB intersects
st_intersects(AB_inter, origin_hunch)
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 2, where the predicate
was `intersects'
 1: 1
 2: (empty)
# MULTI-objects will report if one member does, but doesn't say which
st_intersects(AC_inter, origin_hunch)
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 1, where the predicate
was `intersects`
 1: 1
#  <- st_cast(st_sfc(some_multi, multi_base_desired(point, line, poly...)
st_intersects(AC_inter_pts, origin_hunch)
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 3, where the predicate
was `intersects`
 1: 1
 2: 1
 3: (empty)
```

One may find the multiplicity of returned types annoying and it may be worthwhile to step back in the object creating process to try different initial objects for intersection, so rather then buffer boundaries, convex hulls

```
A_buf_lstring = st_cast(st_convex_hull(A_buffer), 'LINESTRING')
B_buf_lstring = st_cast(st_convex_hull(B_buffer), 'LINESTRING')
st_intersection(A_buf_lstring, B_buf_lstring)
Geometry set for 1 feature 
Geometry type: MULTIPOINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 16.27114 ymin: -19.19564 xmax: 27.32582 ymax: -14.5644
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
MULTIPOINT ((27.32582 -19.19564), (16.27114 -14...
st_cast(st_intersection(A_buf_lstring, B_buf_lstring), 'POINT')
Geometry set for 2 features 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 16.27114 ymin: -19.19564 xmax: 27.32582 ymax: -14.5644
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
POINT (27.32582 -19.19564)
POINT (16.27114 -14.5644)
# this was our AB_inter previously, now relieved of AB_inter[2]
```

plot to study_area

```
plot(study_area)
plot(A_bound, col = 'red', add = TRUE)
plot(B_bound, col = 'blue', add = TRUE)
plot(C_bound, col = 'green', add = TRUE)
plot(D_bound, col = 'brown', add = TRUE)
plot(E_bound, col = 'red', add = TRUE)
plot(AB_inter_pts[1], col = 'red', pch = 21, cex = 1, bg = 'blue')
plot(AB_inter[1], col = 'red', pch = 21, cex = 1, bg = 'blue')
plot(AC_inter_pts[1], col = 'red', pch = 21, cex = 1, bg = 'green')
plot(AC_inter_pts[2], col = 'red', pch = 21, cex = 1, bg = 'green')
plot(AD_inter_pts[1], col = 'red', pch = 21, cex = 1, bg = 'brown')
plot(AE_inter_pts[1], col = 'red', pch = 21, cex = 1, bg = 'red')
```

[image]

Returning to consensus, the unknown origin, has to be in the NE quarter section of A_bound(ary), constrained as it is by B_bound(ary). Points AB_inter and AD_inter_pts are nearly on top of each other. AC & AE would also be nearly on top of them if `df$distance[3] or [5]` had another significant digit, i.e. were just a little longer distances.

We can now return to `geosphere` to check distances back from intersects to great circle origin points A:E ...

Comment: I agree the values of ```locations``` are just so high based on the inputs. Dividing them by a large number seems arbitrary and still those numbers don't fit into Long/Lat. I agree something in the math went wrong.

Comment: And I've now, finally, gone to the link in your question, recognize now the equations above, and will point out the caviat at the bottom, reliable at 20km <. So, might this be approached purely within a `greatCircle` context and intersections there between? Perhaps, rather than just jumping into the code, a little more background about the context of the analysis, its geographic extent, and what is sought either as intermediate products or finals would be in order to qualify the approaches. What are the intersections meant to signify?

Comment: Absolutely. I am using a dataset from another researcher (now deceased) who has locations (Long/Lat degrees) and distances (km) to these locations from an origin location. However, I do not know what location the researcher used as his origin. Because I know the origin location should be in Africa and to constrain the search within a landmass, I am comparing all locations in Africa to each other (pairwise) to find their great circle intersection: https://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/ and similarly the link in my question. The overlaps should consistently reveal the origin.

Comment: Just have some more to do, a little later.

Comment: This is great. What is the significance of ```nQuadSegs''' as the number of segments per quadrant (passed to st_buffer)? Are you saying in most cases, the more the better? Is there a limit for how many segments you want to choose given the precision of other data points? For example, your highest value was 180. Should they all be 180? I am just unfamiliar with this argument, and the documentation online assumes I know more than I do.

Comment: If you look at the plot of the buffers, you see they are jagged, saw-toothed looking, not the graceful arc of a circle, there's a kind of long:long/lat:lat walk plotted resulting in the jaggedness. Increasing `nQuadSegs` should make it 'roundier' even as it remains step-wise, and I imagine the upper limit is RAM. But, I also think, the traectory of intersection influences whether you get `point`, `line`, or `multip`upon what segment(s) it happens. Trying to work out distances, were these field note musings at field camp table, what map, ruler, projection of map, realize df is just sample data.

Comment: The "examine intersection output" section was so helpful, thank you. Trying this on my larger dataset, one of the nested lists of output was a MULTILINESTRING with no POINTS. I looked at the coordinates along this MULTILINESTRING, and they are way out there and not indicative of my unknown origin point. When I am compiling the candidates of POINTs for the unknown origin location, do I just ignore the MULTILINESTRING? Why would there be no POINTs?

Comment: You don't have to ignore them (multilinestring), test as edit above reflects. No points: We, you and me, think if these buffers as infinite points with angles between each successive pair of pts. But buffers are actually step wise segments long:long lat:lat, as you slide one buffer over another  it may be that segments coincide, and such segments are returned.  Going to experiment on improving on buffers...

Comment: Now to exploring distances...

Comment: Thank you for accepting. I still think distances is worth exploring `orig_hunch_cent_5 = rep(st_centroid(origin_hunch), 5)`, as `units::drop_units((st_distance(orig_hunch_cent_5, pts_sfc)/1000)[1,])
[1]  705.729 2232.236 5584.118 2970.960 4586.212` vs df$distance, though haven't explored enough to suggest we've started with the wrong projection assumption (and the indeterminant origin), but, before you write paper worthy of your colleague's data, perhaps another question about determining/estimating projection(s) from distance error, as these are `km`. Thanks for the mystery.

Comment: What makes the results from the multiple intersections of great circles unpublishable? I do see that the estimated distances from the estimated origin are different from the actual distances in the data set. Do you think it's because ```st_distance``` does not account for some aspect of traveling over land? Should the ```distVincentyEllipsoid()``` distance be used instead, since that is a great circle distance? What do you mean by the significance of units of km? Are those inappropriate? These are important points that qualify your answer to this post.

Comment: Nothing makes them unpublishable. I am at present uncertain why the distances are different, or in fact "if" they are different as I was back-measuring from the centroid of the "hunch", which is itself speculative to A:E points (that appear to be capitol cities). I also don't know know if the unknown is a point or an area (ecology could suggest either.) And if made with a ruler on a map on a table (unknown map of unknown projection) could account for differences. Just surprising that 2nd lowest distance buffer has highest error from data. Hence, respectful, patient caution suggests more tests.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. What I actually have from the previous researcher is a population and a distance in km ONLY, and I am the one who assigned the Long/Lat decimal from another larger data set I have. I used larger cities as hubs representing a population's locus, and the Long/Lat decimals were 'chosen' using Google Earth up to the tenths place. Limiting the precision of the Long/Lat decimals was to intentionally incorporate a large area that would represent the sprawl of a population, that they do not really live in this capital city, that there are suburbs and towns and villages.

Comment: You are picking up on something I didn't even consider, that the distances (km) from the previous researcher (that were described to me as great circle distances) could have used a different Long/Lat decimal population location. For my data, I did have to change the Long/Lat for the populations using Google Earth, because the original Long/Lat were eyeballed from paper atlases, and when put into Google Earth could actually be in the middle of the ocean. What you are picking up on is there is a limit to the accuracy I am going to get, since I assigned the Long/Lat. What is the limit?

Comment: Ok, paper atlases (I imagined some, between bouts of malaria, at a camp table, scrutinizing a map with ruler in hand, gin and tonic), but which paper atlas and what projection. Was this you doing these measures or your previous researcher?, i.e. are the answers knowable (and let's stick with great circles...and km) and different long/lat would have as likely meant different map projections (somewhere in the process). I tinkered a little with different projection this morning, but southern Africa, like rare diseases, is a neglected projection zone.  Tack this down before reviewers ask is all.

Comment: The previous researcher's data consist of population and distance (great circles in km). My data set consists of population and Long/Lat decimal I "chose" using Google Earth.  So, without knowing which paper atlas and which projection used by the previous researcher to define population location and thus to calculate his great circle distances, I am doomed to this error between the estimated distances from the estimated origin and the locations I have decreed with Long/Lat and the actual distances from the researcher. Is it enough to just admit this limitation in a paper?

Comment: You could, or just wait for journal review to bring it up (if indeed they do, will depende on methods stated). Population seems inherently areal and the hypothesis should likely hold even with the 'slight' differences in distance noted above. The `st_distance(` of AD_inter_pts[1], AC_inter_pts[2] is 95~km (minimum bounding circle), Returning to the `units::drop_units(` above, `df$distance-units::drop_units(`, all but df$distance[5] are within bound circle distance (and can be accounted by 'where in the circle'). I was just curious. You can write. Link me to an author's pre-print when ready.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution though not optimized but fully functioning.

Sample data:

```
df <- 
data.frame(regionName = c("Anadyr", "Yakutsk", "Magadan"), 
           regionLatitude = c(66.2528, 66.4, 62.9), 
           regionLongitude = c(172.001, 129.167, 153.7),
           dist_from = c(2000000, 3000000, NA) #m
           )

  regionName regionLatitude regionLongitude dist_from
1     Anadyr        66.2528         172.001     2e+06
2    Yakutsk        66.4000         129.167     3e+06
3    Magadan        62.9000         153.700        NA
```

`dist_from` - is a sample problem - distance (in meters from Anadyr and Yakutsk).
I decided to take polar regions because you were also asking about Anchorage and Anadyr in one of your other questions and because equidistant circles agound the region centers will be most deformed when plotted.

First we can produce circles composed of equidistant points:

```
library(tidyverse)    
steps <- 360 # you can adjust precision and speed of your calculations here
step_angle <- 2 * pi / steps
singularVectors <- 
  tibble(singular_azimuths =
           seq(0, 2 * pi - (step_angle), step_angle)
  ) 


endCoord <- function(lon, lat, bearing, dist, ...){
    bearing <- -1*(bearing / pi * 180 - 90) # conversion of radians to bearing degrees 
    maptools::gcDestination(lon, lat, bearing, dist, ...) %>% 
      c() %>% 
      `names<-`(c("long", "lat"))
}

df_equidistant <- 
crossing(df, singularVectors) %>% 
    data.frame(
    (Vectorize(endCoord, SIMPLIFY = T)(lon = .$regionLongitude, 
                                       lat = .$regionLatitude,
                                       bearing = .$singular_azimuths,
                                       dist = .$dist_from) %>% 
       t 
    )
  )
```

We get coordinates of these equidistant points:

```
head(df_equidistant)
  regionName regionLatitude regionLongitude dist_from singular_azimuths     long      lat
1     Anadyr        66.2528         172.001     2e+06        0.00000000 141.0675 62.84646
2     Anadyr        66.2528         172.001     2e+06        0.01745329 141.3115 62.64018
3     Anadyr        66.2528         172.001     2e+06        0.03490659 141.5596 62.43540
4     Anadyr        66.2528         172.001     2e+06        0.05235988 141.8119 62.23213
5     Anadyr        66.2528         172.001     2e+06        0.06981317 142.0681 62.03041
6     Anadyr        66.2528         172.001     2e+06        0.08726646 142.3281 61.83026
```

We can plot them as circles:

```
p <-
ggplot(df_equidistant) +   
geom_point(aes(regionLongitude, regionLatitude, color = regionName), data = df) +   
geom_text(aes(regionLongitude, regionLatitude, label = regionName), data = df, vjust = 1) +   
geom_point(aes(long, lat, color = regionName )) +
scale_color_discrete(name = "Distance from")
```

We get the following graph:

[image]

Here is a supplementary function (haversine theorem) calculating distance between two coordinates: you can use this or find another in external library:

```
EARTH_RADIUS <- 6378137

mapDistanceHaversine <- function(reg1, reg2) {
  if(any(is.na(c(reg1, reg2)))) return (NA)

  if (all(reg1 == reg2)) return(NA)
    if(reg1[['long']]<0) reg1[['long']] <- reg1[['long']] + 360
    if(reg2[['long']]<0) reg2[['long']] <- reg2[['long']] + 360
    
    reg1 <- reg1 * pi / 180
    reg2 <- reg2 * pi / 180
    
    d <- 2 * asin(sqrt(
      sin((reg2[['lat']] - reg1[['lat']]) / 2)^2 +
        (
          cos(reg1[['lat']]) * 
            cos(reg2[['lat']]) * 
            (sin((reg2[['long']] - reg1[['long']]) / 2)^2)
        )
    ))
    d * EARTH_RADIUS
}
```

Then we calculate distances between pairs of points (this part must be optimized later on):

```
outerList <- function(a,b, fun) {
  outer(a, b, function(x,y) vapply(seq_along(x), function(i) fun(x[[i]], y[[i]]), numeric(1)))
}

cross_distances <- 
df_equidistant %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  transmute(eqdc = list(list(long = long, lat = lat) )) %>% 
  pull %>% 
  lapply(unlist) %>% 
  outerList(., ., mapDistanceHaversine)
```

We get pairs of points and distances between them:

```
cross_distances[1:7,1:7]
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
[1,]        NA  26114.93  52227.98 78337.27 104440.93 130537.07 156623.81
[2,]  26114.93        NA  26114.93 52227.98  78337.27 104440.93 130537.07
[3,]  52227.98  26114.93        NA 26114.93  52227.98  78337.27 104440.93
[4,]  78337.27  52227.98  26114.93       NA  26114.93  52227.98  78337.27
[5,] 104440.93  78337.27  52227.98 26114.93        NA  26114.93  52227.98
[6,] 130537.07 104440.93  78337.27 52227.98  26114.93        NA  26114.93
[7,] 156623.81 130537.07 104440.93 78337.27  52227.98  26114.93        NA
```

We find the smallest distance:

```
point1 <- which(cross_distances == min(cross_distances, na.rm = T), arr.ind = T)
```

We have got two points (belonging to Anadyr and Yakutsk circles):

```
points
     row col
[1,] 878  64
[2,]  64 878
```

Actually it is the first solution (crossing of circles A and B).

We need to find the second solution (taking one of the next smallest distances):

```
  point2 <- which(cross_distances == Rfast::nth(cross_distances, 5, na.rm = T), arr.ind = T)
```

The coordinates of these solutions will be means of longitudes and latitudes for each pair of points:

```
solutions <-
  rbind(
    df_equidistant[point1[,1],] %>% 
      summarise(long = mean(long),
                lat = mean(lat)),
    df_equidistant[point2[,1],] %>% 
      summarise(long = mean(long),
                lat = mean(lat))
  )

solutions
      long      lat
1 161.7240 53.62795
2 189.2872 78.87114
```

We can now plot them:

```
p + 
geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat), solutions, color = "green", size = 3, pch = 17)
```

[image]

**APPENDED**

Possible ways to optimize the code above.

1. It is quite possible to assign some small number to `steps` and then use binary search of `singular_azimuths` with minimum distance betweens circle points.
2. `singular_azimuths` can be calculated not to the whole cirlce but only to its half (azimuth-pi/2; azimuth+pi/2). For azimuth calculation `maptools::gzAzimuth()` or alike functions can be used.

Comment: Thank you for going step-by-step, explaining along the way. From your code: ```endCoord <- function(lon, lat, bearing, dist, ...){
    bearing <- -1*(bearing / pi * 180 - 90) # conversion of radians to bearing degrees``` where did you get the original bearing information? I do not have this information, and as discussed in the comments I am not sure an unbiased way to generate the bearings if I don't know the destination location.

Comment: @simpson Hi. I generate vector of bearings from 0 to 2*pi (full circle). I call them `singular_azimuths`. I convert generated azimuths to bearings because trigonometrical 0 is turned right and the angle increases counter clockwise, I use radians for them. Bearings start at North (top) and increase clockwise, measured in degrees. You can convert the code and generate bearings directly. I use `singular_azimuts` as they help to work with euclidean coordinates and schemes as well

Comment: You can try this code with other coordinates and distances